# prefersLargeTitles giving constraint errors

Tags: ios, swift

`preferslargeTitles` giving constraint errors, i had earlier completed a small app with the same code but no error then , here not only is the error on font size 40 but also no color red, there is no other code , other then pinning the table to view. The warning is

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.

code

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "LaViva Hotel"
     
     
    //customization
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
     
    
    if let customFont = UIFont(name: "Rubik-Medium", size: 40.0) {
      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 200/255, green: 70/255, blue: 70/255, alpha: 1), NSAttributedString.Key.font: customFont]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run your code but I didn't find any error as you mentioned, Also I have changed some line of code and it's working, Now you can use as follows:-

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "LaViva Hotel"
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true     
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes =
   [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 200/255, green: 70/255, blue: 70/255, alpha: 1),
    NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Rubik-Medium", size: 40) ??
                UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)]
```

If you want more clarification, you should mention what type of output you exactly want, share some screenshots as well!